# Rails send_data return HTTP error 406

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, download, xls

I have a little problem on an export as XLS from my database.
I use the gem `to_xls` and after folowing the documentation I have this error that I don't know how to get ride of and launch the download of my file:

controller:

```rb
def export
  @subscribes = Subscribe.all
  respond_to do |format |
    format.xls { send_data@subscribes.to_xls, disposition: 'attachment', : filename = > 'Subscribes.xls' }
  end
end
```

My MIME file

```rb
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.ms-excel", :xls
```

And so, the error that I got with the full header:

```rb
Request URL:https://localhost:3000/subscribes/export
Request Method:GET
Status Code:406 Not Acceptable

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36

Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Server:thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
X-Request-Id:a5be7889994f1035818d6a554f991636
X-Runtime:0.012001
X-UA-Compatible:IE=Edge
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `format.xls`, you have to append `.xls` to the url. Try

```
curl -v https://localhost:3000/subscribes/export.xls
```

Otherwise, you can move `send_data` out of the `respond_to` block.

Comment: I got the same issue with csv attachment.
It's work for me when add the ```.csv``` extension to the url